# Как скрыть блок css?

Tags: html, css

Возник вопрос. Использую псевдокласс hover для того чтобы скрыть блок, но после того как я убираю курсор с блока он снова появляется. Каким образом можно сделать так, чтобы когда ты первый раз перемещаете курсор на объект он полностью исчезал и больше не появлялся пока пользователь не перезагрузит страницу?

Comment: js вам в помощь.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно так:

```css
span {
  background-color: blue;
  margin: 10px;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  float: left
}
```

```html
<span onmouseover="this.style.opacity='0'"></span>
<span onmouseover="this.style.opacity='0'"></span>
<span onmouseover="this.style.opacity='0'"></span>
<span onmouseover="this.style.opacity='0'"></span>
<span onmouseover="this.style.opacity='0'"></span>
<span onmouseover="this.style.opacity='0'"></span>
<span onmouseover="this.style.opacity='0'"></span>
<span onmouseover="this.style.opacity='0'"></span>
<span onmouseover="this.style.opacity='0'"></span>
<span onmouseover="this.style.opacity='0'"></span>
<span onmouseover="this.style.opacity='0'"></span>
<span onmouseover="this.style.opacity='0'"></span>
```

Answer (score 3):

```
let block = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('blockSelector'),0);
block.forEach(element => {
    element.addEventListener('mouseover', ()=> {element.style.opacity = 0});
})
```

где фраза 'blockSelector', укажи CSS селектор ('.hiding_block' , например) в кавычках

Comment: через display элементы будут прыгать, т.к. они пропадают из dom

Comment: Ты прав - подправил)